# What does it mean to be the 'strong, silent type'?

Tags: meaning, expressions, connotation

If someone says you're *the strong, silent type* is it a compliment?

Comment: sure, generally it's a compliment made to a man.  The English learner's site is perfect for questions like this.

Comment: If it's someone who finds a lot of chit chat annoying, yes.  If it's someone who finds it frustrating that you tend toward being unresponsive (if that is how you were perceived), then no.  It really depends on the particular person and their feelings toward you.  //  It seems likely to me that this was a bit of teasing.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is quite subtle. Traditionally this has been said by a woman in defence of a man. It could however convey a hint of sarcasm depending on the tone and circumstances.

**Example**

*"Your husband John doesn't have much to say for himself does he?"*

*"Well, I know he doesn't talk a lot. Let's just say he's the strong, silent type."*

Remaining silent is often taken to be an indicator of shyness or lack of confidence. These can be seen as negatives. Strength is considered to be a good quality.

By putting the two together, you say that although the person does not talk much, this is not a sign of weakness.

Answer (score 0):

Women, it has been said, are notorious for being chatterboxes, social gossipy creatures. Many claim, usually it's men,  that women spend far too much time talking to friends or family on the phone or at parties and social gatherings. In contrast, men tend to be more quiet *at home*, and traditionally, men only speak when something important has to be said.

While all of the above sounds terribly sexist and cliché, there are some grains of truth. Likewise the expression, **the strong silent type**, is a cliché but it is meant as a compliment. Because a man (or woman) who is silent means someone who is in control and only speaks when there is a real necessity. “Real men” do things, they don't waste time in chatter; hence a *silent man* implies a a person who is a doer, and a *strong man*, emphasizes his masculinity and his physical strength. Put the two characteristics together and the “strong silent type”  is usually a man who works hard  and doesn't buckle under pressure,  and speaks only when it is absolutely necessary.

*[Your dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/strong-silent-type)* defines it as

> **strong-silent-type**
>
> - A quiet or emotionally reserved man of action.
>     <sub>**Usage notes**</sub>
> - While the phrase is almost always used in reference to a man, it may, on occasion, be applied to a woman.